# Janela fechando automaticamente PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, gui, pysimplegui

estou tendo um problema com o PySimpleGUI. O programa está retornando o valor correto no `output`, porém quando clico no `button` para que o programa faça os cálculos ele fecha a janela muito rapidamente logo após exibir o `output`.

Aqui está o código:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('TanBlue')



#layout
layout = [
    [sg.Text("Sexo:", size=(10,0)),sg.Radio("M", "RADIO1",key="masculino"),sg.Radio("F","RADIO1",key="feminino")],

    [sg.Text("Biotipo:",size=(10,0)), sg.Radio("Ectomorfo","RADIO2",key="ecto"),sg.Radio("Mesomorfo","RADIO2",key="meso"), sg.Radio("Endomorfo","RADIO2",key="endo")],

    [sg.Text("Altura(cm):",size=(10,0)), sg.InputText(size=(6,0), key="altura")],

    [sg.Text("Peso(Kg):",size=(10,0)), sg.InputText(size=(6,0), key="peso")],

    [sg.Text("Idade:", size=(10,0)), sg.InputText(size=(6,0),key="idade")],

    [sg.Button("Calcular TMB", size=(10,0)), sg.Exit()],

    [sg.Text("Sua TMB:", size=(10,0)) ,sg.Output(size=(15,0))]
]
#janela
janela = sg.Window("Taxa metabólica basal").layout(layout)
#extrair os dados da tela
Button, values = janela.Read()

masculino = values['masculino']
feminino = values['feminino']  
ecto = values['ecto'] 
meso = values['meso']
endo = values['endo']   
altura = int(values['altura'])
peso = float(values['peso'])
idade = int(values['idade'])

if(masculino == True):    
    tmb = 66 + 13.7*peso + 5*altura - 6.8*idade   
elif(feminino == True): 
    tmb = 665 + 9.6*peso + 1.8*altura - 4.7*idade



print(str(tmb)+" Kcal")
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução para este problema é simples, o que acontece é que como seu código não tem um loop de while para dar continuidade após realizar uma ação dentro do seu GUI, como por exemplo coletar os dados passados e realizar o cálculo por exemplo ele fecha.

Para resolver isso eu eu adicionei um loop infinito ***while*** que acaba quando o ***GUI*** é fechado ou o botão ***Exit*** é clicado e especifiquei os eventos que ocorrem dentro do programa

> Mantive a parte do layout

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('TanBlue')

#layout
layout = [
    [sg.Text("Sexo:", size=(10,0)),sg.Radio("M", "RADIO1",key="masculino"),sg.Radio("F","RADIO1",key="feminino")],

    [sg.Text("Biotipo:",size=(10,0)), sg.Radio("Ectomorfo","RADIO2",key="ecto"),sg.Radio("Mesomorfo","RADIO2",key="meso"), sg.Radio("Endomorfo","RADIO2",key="endo")],

    [sg.Text("Altura(cm):",size=(10,0)), sg.InputText(size=(6,0), key="altura")],

    [sg.Text("Peso(Kg):",size=(10,0)), sg.InputText(size=(6,0), key="peso")],

    [sg.Text("Idade:", size=(10,0)), sg.InputText(size=(6,0),key="idade")],

    [sg.Button("Calcular TMB", size=(10,0)), sg.Exit()],

    [sg.Text("Sua TMB:", size=(10,0)) ,sg.Output(size=(100,0))]
]
```

- Segue a parte modificada

> Mudei ***sg.Window("Taxa metabólica basal").layout(layout)*** da janela para ***sg.Window("Taxa metabólica basal",layout)*** tem o mesmo resultado de uma forma mais compacta.

```
#janela
janela = sg.Window("Taxa metabólica basal",layout)
```

> De acordo com a própria documentação do ***PySimpleGui*** o ***sg.Window*** tem os parâmetros ***Title e layout*** dentro da função sendo: ***sg.window("Título",layout")*** a forma mais simples de usar, mas claro que você pode usar também o ***.layout(layout)*** assim como você usou.

Primeiramente aqui eu coloquei o loop como dito antes para dar segmento nas ações do usuário enquanto a sua GUI não for fechada.

> Mudei o nome do ***Button*** para ***event*** mas isso não influencia em muita coisa não é só por uma questão de leitura

```
#extrair os dados da tela
while True:
    event, values = janela.Read()
```

> Aqui embaixo adicionei duas condições relacionadas aos eventos que ocorrem dentro da GUI, sendo eles respectivamente o ato de clicar no botão ***"Exit"*** e no ***"Calcular TMB"***.

```
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break

    elif event == "Calcular TMB":
        masculino = values['masculino']
        feminino = values['feminino']  
        ecto = values['ecto'] 
        meso = values['meso']
        endo = values['endo']   
        altura = int(values['altura'])
        peso = float(values['peso'])
        idade = int(values['idade'])

        if(masculino == True):    
            tmb = 66 + 13.7*peso + 5*altura - 6.8*idade   

        elif(feminino == True): 
            tmb = 665 + 9.6*peso + 1.8*altura - 4.7*idade
```

Nessa parte aqui eu troquei o modo de print e coloquei ele para aparecer formatado

> O resultado ainda é o mesmo porém desse jeito caso o número seja muito quebrado como por exemplo: ***785.99999999999999*** o programa só vai deixar vísivel ***785.99***

```
        print(f"{tmb:.2f} Kcal")
```

e por fim coloquei isso aqui para forçar a fechada da janela quando o código todo acabar de rodar.

```
janela.close()
```

Espero ter ajudado!
Segue o link para documentação oficial: https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Código completo:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('TanBlue')

#layout
layout = [
    [sg.Text("Sexo:", size=(10,0)),sg.Radio("M", "RADIO1",key="masculino"),sg.Radio("F","RADIO1",key="feminino")],

    [sg.Text("Biotipo:",size=(10,0)), sg.Radio("Ectomorfo","RADIO2",key="ecto"),sg.Radio("Mesomorfo","RADIO2",key="meso"), sg.Radio("Endomorfo","RADIO2",key="endo")],

    [sg.Text("Altura(cm):",size=(10,0)), sg.InputText(size=(6,0), key="altura")],

    [sg.Text("Peso(Kg):",size=(10,0)), sg.InputText(size=(6,0), key="peso")],

    [sg.Text("Idade:", size=(10,0)), sg.InputText(size=(6,0),key="idade")],

    [sg.Button("Calcular TMB", size=(10,0)), sg.Exit()],

    [sg.Text("Sua TMB:", size=(10,0)) ,sg.Output(size=(100,0))]
]
#janela
janela = sg.Window("Taxa metabólica basal",layout)

#extrair os dados da tela
while True:
    event, values = janela.Read() 

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit": # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break

    elif event == "Calcular TMB":
        masculino = values['masculino']
        feminino = values['feminino']  
        ecto = values['ecto'] 
        meso = values['meso']
        endo = values['endo']   
        altura = int(values['altura'])
        peso = float(values['peso'])
        idade = int(values['idade'])

        if(masculino == True):    
            tmb = 66 + 13.7*peso + 5*altura - 6.8*idade   

        elif(feminino == True): 
            tmb = 665 + 9.6*peso + 1.8*altura - 4.7*idade

        print(f"{tmb:.2f} Kcal")

janela.close()
```